# How do I read an image from a base64 encoded string in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, base64

I'm getting a XML containing image which is base64 encoded.I've  to decode that & need to display a image.Any suggestions.............

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) on cocoawithlove.com about decoding base64 on both Mac OS and iPhone.

Here's a Mac OS way to create an NSImage:

```
unsigned char* data;
int width, height;

NSBitmapImageRep* rep;
rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:&data
                                              pixelsWide:width
                                              pixelsHigh:height
                                           bitsPerSample:8
                                         samplesPerPixel:4
                                                hasAlpha:YES
                                                isPlanar:NO
                                          colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                            bitmapFormat:NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat
                                             bytesPerRow:32
                                            bitsPerPixel:32];
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(8, 8)];
[image addRepresentation:rep];
```

This works on the iPhone to create an UIImage:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, 32, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Comment: Any recommendations on getting the width and height?